# How to configure Astyanax connection pool to dismiss any client requests (single Cassandra node development environments)

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

in a Cassandra/Astyanax development environment, I'm running a single/local Cassandra node. When this single Cassandra node goes down (for whatever reason), any Astyanax based client code (mutation batch, queries ...) fail with something like that:

```
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.NoAvailableHostsException: NoAvailableHostsException: [host=None(0.0.0.0):0, latency=0(0), attempts=0]No hosts to borrow from
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.<init>(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:30)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl.newExecuteWithFailover(TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl.java:80)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:248)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:532)
```

and this exception is logged for each subsequent Astyanax-based client request, resulting in the above log spam. Basically, I'm asking if there is a way to configure an Astyanax connection pool in a way to stop accepting requests and ideally provide some sort of callback which allows me to shutdown my Astyanax-based client application (e.g. our server application).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a bad choice, the whole point of Cassandra is to build a distributed, multi-node cluster which can handle failures, however you could catch that specific exception and disregard it in java without doing the costly logging.

```
try {
    // lots of C* stuff
} catch (NoAvailableHostsException ex) {
    // Swallow exception
}
```

Also Astyanax doesn't accept requests, its an API not a server, Cassandra is the server. You can tell Cassandra to stop excepting requests using the JMX functionality. You could [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-7758/gcitp/index.html) a call to the `stopRPCServer()` JMX function in `org.apache.cassandra.db.StorageService`.